# Custom AlertDialog Borders

Tags: android, customdialog

I am creating a custom dialog. Its example code is:

```
final AlertDialog dialog;

protected AlertDialog createDialog(int dialogId) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(parent);
    AlertDialog fDialog = null;

    switch(dialogId) {
        case Constants.cusDialogtId:
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(parent);
            builder.setTitle("Title");
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)parent.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customdialog, null);
            builder.setView(view);
            fDialog = builder.create();
            break;
    }
    dialog = fDialog;
    return dialog;
}
```

The problem is that when the dialog is shown, it has a gray background of the native dialog whose some top and bottom border is also shown with my custom dialog.
Is there some way to show only my custom dialog view...???

The XML I am using is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/bgsmall" >
<EditText android:id="@+id/redeemamount"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
android:hint="Enter amount"
android:inputType="numberDecimal">
</EditText>             
<Button android:id="@+id/submitRedeemAmountButton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="40dip"
android:text="Submit"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:background="@drawable/buttoncorner"
android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dip">
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you provide the xml for customdialog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can remove the borders by using `AlertDialog.Builder`.

What you can do is create a `CustomDialog` class that extends `Dialog` and in the constructor of your `CustomDialog` you inflate your `customdialog.xml`.

Also you will need to create a custom `style` for your dialog, that hides the borders. Here is an example:

```
    <style
      name="CustomStyle"
      parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
      <item
          name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
      <item
          name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

Also define the transparent color:

```
   <color
      name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

And you will create your dialog using :

```
    CustomDialog dialog=new CustomDialog(this,R.style.CustomStyle);
```

Comment: Can also use @android:color/transparent ;)

Answer (score 2):

Create a [custom theme](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    </style> 
</resources>
```

then use it:

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(parent, R.style.CustomDialog);
```

**Update**

The constructor above is indeed API 11+. To work around this you need to extend AlertDialog (since its constructors are `protected`) and and then use constructor with theme parameter. To insert your custom view follow the instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) - the `FrameLayout` trick described at the beginning.

Comment: yeah, this is possible since API Level 11. depends on what is your target.

Comment: Not working. AlertDialog.Builder() takes only the single Context parameter.

Comment: See the update. Note the `FrameLayout` trick needed to insert your View.